# Can we have hints for [image]s and [video]s in the Flagged Posts tool?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags, moderators

I'm reviewing flags, and I see this:

[image: flagged post]

It looks like mild lunacy, and I'd probably flag as low quality and move on. However, looking at the actual answer shows that it's not *quite* as mad as it seemed:

[image: answer showing YouTube video]

It looks like a potentially useful answer from a new user who could fix up the post.

Is it possible to have `[video]` and `[image]` placeholders in the Flagged Posts tool so that it's easy to see when there is relevant information that we might be missing? I would not have expanded this post given its content.

Answer (score 1):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

With the [Moderator Dashboard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/328838/179041) design changes, rolled out in 2019, you can expand the flagged post and see any images or YouTube videos linked in-line.

I posted an answer to the Formatting Sandbox, and flagged it myself to get you some screenshots. Here's the flag modal, not expanded:

[image: Un-expanded]

Expanding the flag results in the following view:

[image: Expanded flag modal with YouTube video clearly visible]

---

I can also confirm that images work in much the same manner.

Comment: tfw your post gets [status-completed] 7 years later

Comment: @fredley - Yeah I've been on a bit of a lazy crusade trying to triage and prioritise our bugs and feature requests. Got us down from like 300+ to 192 over the course of 2 years.